# produce json with hashes that have the same key name - perl

Tags: json, perl

I am aiming to produce the following json:

```
{
     "nervous" : {
         { "id" : 1 },
         { "id" : 2 },
         { "id" : 3}
      }
}
```

I am aware that hashes don't accept a key with the same name more than once, but is there a  way of producing the above json? Currently I'm doing the following:

```
use JSON;

sub json_test {

    my %moods;
    $moods{'happy'} = "am happy";
    $moods{'excited'} = "am excited";
    $moods{'nervous'}{'id'} = 2;
    $moods{'nervous'}{'id'} = 3;
    $moods{'nervous'}{'id'} = 4;

    return to_json( \%moods, {utf8 => 1, pretty => 1});
}

my $return = json_test();
print $return;
```

I'm pretty sure it would be valid json data as each id is within its own object. Could someone please advise, I'm completely new to Perl (but am pretty excited to learn it)

Comment: JSONLint claims your JSON isn't valid, I think you meant http://codepad.org/UcVoiHrt

Comment: Your example of what you want to produce is not valid JSON. Your `"nervous"` should be a list.

Comment: ah yes you're (both) right, will update now

Comment: actually I left it as the invalid version so people won't get confused when looking at the accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. An object `{…}` requires key-value pairs. You probably want to use an array `[…]` instead:

```
{
     "nervous" : [
         { "id" : 1 },
         { "id" : 2 },
         { "id" : 3}
      ]
}
```

which could be generated by the Perl code

```
my $moods = {
     nervous => [
         { id => 1 },
         { id => 2 },
         { id => 3}
      ]
};

to_json($moods, { ut8 =>1, pretty => 1 });
```

or

```
my %moods;
$moods{'happy'} = "am happy";
$moods{'excited'} = "am excited";
push @{ $moods{nervous} }, { id => 2 };
push @{ $moods{nervous} }, { id => 3 };
push @{ $moods{nervous} }, { id => 4 };
```

Comment: eh, I find it kind of confusing how you can 'transform' the variable into an array and push to it, if that's what's happening?

Comment: It's not being transformed. The hash is storing an arrayref in the nervous key which contains three hashrefs of id => value pairs.

Comment: @a7omiton That's called *autovivification* – if there's nothing inside a variable, and you use it as an array reference in a “lvalue context”, Perl puts an array ref there. If you use an empty variable as a hash reference, Perl puts an hash ref there. If you use it as a string, you get an empty string etc. It's a tremendously useful feature.